# Disable text selection callouts in iOS

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css

I know you can disable the callout when a user long-taps on a *link* using this:

```
body {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none !important;
}

a {
    -webkit-user-select: none !important;
}
```

But what about the text selection menu? My use case is a `contentEditable` region in which the user should be allowed to select content, but the callout appears on top of the app's own formatting menu.

Here's the callout I'm referring to:

[image]

Comment: What is your requirement

Comment: To disable the shown callout when text is selected.

Comment: I have this same question. Were you ever able to figure out how to do this?

Comment: Nope. Don't believe it's currently possible.

Answer (score -3):

`here is your answer i am not sure but it's work`

```
 -webkit-user-select: none;  /* Chrome all / Safari all */
 -moz-user-select: none;/* Firefox all */
 -ms-user-select: none;
```

Comment: That disables text selection altogether, which is not desired. The user needs to be able to select text, but without the callout.