# disable text selection callout in ios

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, text, selection, callouts

It was an old question, [Disable text selection callouts in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22240674/disable-text-selection-callouts-in-ios), but maybe now it's possible. Anyone know how to hide the ios text selection callout or how to customize it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/65199179/631869